# Как обозначить повторяющуюся деятельность на BPMN схеме бизнес-процесса?

Tags: процесс, блок-схема

Всем привет! Моя текущая BPMN схема приложена к сообщению. Как её дополнить и прописать следующую активность - врач в первый рабочий день нового месяца собирает статистику по диагнозам которые проставил своим пациентам за прошедший месяц.
Буду очень благодарен за корректировки.
В настоящий момент я прописал это так - **в процессе "Врач" добавлено две активности, одна из которых описывает сбор ежемесячной статистики**, *но это 100% неверно*. [image: Схема бизнес-процесса]